# Error when running heroku run rake db:migrate 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

whenever i run heroku run rake db:migrate 3 , i get

rake aborted!
    Can't load WDM!

```
WDM is not supported on your system. For a cross-platform alternative,
we recommend using Listen: http://github.com/guard/listen
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: it simply says that it doesn't support Windows Directory Monitor (WDM), and therefore recommends using Listen, which is great alternative

Comment: I installed Listen but it didnt do anything :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@user2240307 Throw your windows gems in a platform group in your gemfile.

```
#WINDOWS Gems That don't play well with nix
platforms :mswin do 
  gem "wdm", :group => [:development, :test]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku restart
```

made it work properly again if not change your application environment develop it on `LINUX` OS.

Set up Ruby, Rails with RVM then set up DB configuration. It will surely run

Comment: I was faced the same problem. I set up same app on Ubuntu and it's worked for me.

Comment: it didnt work..., and im afraid that if i switch my OS to ubuntu, another problem will pop out which installing Rails on the ubuntu, because i heard that its hard to install :(

Comment: No it's very easy to set up rails on Ubuntu. You only need to install or setup the **rvm** first then ruby on rails world will become very easy.

Comment: I was faced same problem on my windows machine. I switched my OS to Ubuntu. Set up MYSQL, RVM then all version of Rubies and rails. It become 50% faster to work with ruby on rails on Linux as compared to windows.

Comment: As a work around you can also do copy the gemfile and gemfile lock which from linux system rails application, then deploy it on Heroku. It will surely work.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sumit,  i will try set up ubuntu and look how it goes